# apply subdomain mapping to an addon domain in Hostgator

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domain names, both hosted on hostgator  (the unlimited domain baby plan)
1. foo.com (This was the first domain to be registered on HG)
2. bar.com (I added this as an addon domain in HG)

The directory structure has `/public_html/` which keeps all of the files and subdirs for foo.com

`/public_html/` has a subdir called `bar` (i.e. `public_html/bar/`) which keeps all of the files for bar.com. This was set up by HG during the addon domain process. So files for bar.com would show up like this: `/public_html/bar/process.php`

I want this:
`sss.bar.com/fff` -> `bar.com/process.php?sub=sss&file=fff`
But I'm getting lookup failures.

This is what I tried: (this file is `/public_html/bar/.htaccess` - there is a separate .htaccess in the parent dir for foo.com, it has one unrelated rule)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in PHP, and
# run the main process.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /process.php?sub=%1

# Map all requests to the 'path' get variable in process.php
RewriteRule ^process\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /process.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Tests:
1. `bar.com/myFile` -> generates a GET parm in process.php of [file]=>myFile - good.
2. `test.bar.com/myFile` does not work.

The error is:

> The server at test.bar.com can't be found, because
>   the DNS lookup failed

3. `bar.foo.com/file1`  results in GETs of [file]=>/process.php [sub]=>bar

I think it may be due to the way that HG structures my addon domains - as a subdomain.  So now it thinks I'm trying to remap a subdomain of a subdomain...if that makes sense.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
After wildcard subdomains was added and .htaccess modified as below, it looks as though it's working as needed.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bar\.com$  

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.bar\.com$  

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  index.php?userId=%1&fileName=$1
```

Comment: If `test.bar.com` has not been registered then it won't be found on DNS server and .htaccess cannot change that behavior.

Comment: My intent here is to have users of my site have the ability to share a custom link (ex `mary.bar.com/awesome` would translate to call `process.php` with GET parms of `userId="mary"` and `filename="awesome"`   
Since I don't know who the users will be ahead of time, I'm pursuing a wildcard route.  I'll update later when I'm able to test out some of the suggestions.  Thanks for contributing.

Comment: escape the `.` in `bar.com` with a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that your `test.bar.com` subdomain is unknown to the world-wide DNS system. For it to know, you will have to register it with the DNS system. (If this is just for your private use and not public, you can use your systems `/etc/hosts` file to map the name to the server ip)

I assume Hostgator is the `Domain Name Registrar` for both `foo.com` (*primary domain*) and `bar.com` (*addon domain*) and you have access rights to the Domain control panels (CPanel/Plesk/etc.) to do the required.

When you bought an addon domain (`bar.com`) for your primary domain (`foo.com`), Hostgator would have setup a DNS `CNAME` (*Canonical Name Record*) record for **`www`**.`bar.com` pointing to the same `Host` record (also called A record/Address record) of your primary domain, so that both domains share the same hosting. So you now have to do the same thing for **`test`**.`bar.com` subdomain. You can find a short guide here from Hostgator: [How to change DNS zones (MX, CNAME, and A records)](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-change-dns-zones-mx-cname-and-a-records).
**Note**: Changes to DNS records may need a few hours to take effect.

This would be annoying for you to set them up manually each time you want a new subdomain. Many Domain name registrars (including [Hostgator](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/wildcard-dns-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it)) also support a feature called WildCard domains. They allow you to use `*` (wildcard) for the `CNAME` record pointing to your primary domain. This makes `whatever.bar.com`, point to the same address  `www.bar.com` is pointing.

To support individual sites for your primary, addon domains and their subdomains, Apache uses domain name-based virtual hosts. If you want to load the same site for `whatever.bar.com` as `www.bar.com`, Apache allows `*` wildcard in [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive. Make sure `*.bar.com` as a ServerAlias is setup in `www.bar.com` VirtualHost configuration. Otherwise, you have to setup separate VirtualHost configurations for each subdomain.
**Note:** There is also a [`VirtualDocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) apache directive that can be used to provide separate document roots depending on the domain name.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response, and appreciate the additional education.  I added a wildcard subdomain in HG this morning.  Apparently it takes several hours to be seen, so have been unable to test it out yet.
I actually want to have many subdomains (for each user of my site), so having a wildcard seems to be the way to go.
I'll post the results of my testing tomorrow.  Cheers!

Comment: DNS record changes are not instant; I have added a note on this in my answer. With the`CNAME` wildcard record set, all your subdomains are available (even before you think about its name). What each sudomain does, depends on how you configured your Apache web server.

Comment: Got it working!  I have updated the question to reflect the changes I made.  Any potential problems with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

### Working example

Input: http://mary.bar.com/awesome/
Result: index.php GET parms:

```
Array
(
    [userId] => mary
    [fileName] => awesome
)
```

And here is the final .htaccess I got to work once the wildcard subdomain were setup.  Explanation added (mainly to help me)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# 1. Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in PHP
# 2. Parse out the filename (must have a trailing "/" on the end)
# 3. Pass the vars into index.php script
# Make sure a wildcard subdomain is setup (takes 24-48hrs to propagate) and points to the addon domain folder
# ex: "public_html/addon-domain-name.tld"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# make sure we don't process "www.domain.com" or "domain.com".  This will just default to index.php with no GET vars
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bar\.com$

# This part pulls out the subdomain from the front of the URL & stores it in "%1"
# Note: it is possible that the subdomain can have multiple parts (ex bob.smith.domain.com) and still work
#       The user id is either numeric or string [Aa-Zz], so add error checks inside index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.bar\.com$

# IMPT: do not rewrite the rule until the trailing filename is parsed out
#       otherwise .htaccess will try to parse out something from index.php
# Parse out the filename that comes after domain.com (stored in "$1").  A trailing "/" is required.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  index.php?userId=%1&fileName=$1
```